# Import "text" strings, to create, automatically, empty pages in MediaWiki

Tags: drupal, mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am using MediaWiki (Sometimes I think that it could be better to use Drupal) to create a wiki.

I have tried to find out a correct api or something similar to import a table (csv, xml, or another format) with text fields.

The idea is to bring a document with "name-pages" and "tags" to create automatically empty pages. 
Finally, the users will see that there are new empty pages to fill!.

And every day pass a scheduler (something like [Feed Import in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import)) to bring new pages. I mean, if the text exists, don't do anything; however, it the text is new, create a new wikimedia page!

I don't find the correct api to do this. Somebody knows any way to do this?

Thank you

Regards!

Comment: Are you talking about a [web API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) or internal API (what PHP method to call)? Have you considered using a [maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Maintenance_scripts)?

Comment: Yes!! It could be solution. But I have found the "populate category" 
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/REL1_28/maintenance/populateCategory.php

The idea is to find the same for something like this:  "populatepage".

But i understand that it could be impossible because the structure of the table "page"
The idea is to find the same for something like this:  "populatepage".

But i understand that it could be impossible because the structure of the table "page".

Comment: populateCategory is not really what you think - all the populate* scripts deal with restoring internal consistency by updating various secondary tables (the primary storage for categories is the page text). [edit.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Edit.php) and [importTextFiles.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportTextFiles.php) are more similar to what you are looking for.